# Laravel 9 html form submit throws 405. Expects PUT, request is GET

Tags: php, laravel, php-8, laravel-9

I'm trying to create a simple CRUD application with Laravel 9. I've run into a problem with HTML forms. I've created a page where you can edit data on rabbits existing in my database.

**My form**

```html
<form name="editRabbitForm" action="{{ url('/rabbit/update') }}" method="PUT">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <!-- here be input fields -->
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
  <a type="button" href="/rabbits" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
</form>
```

**`web.php` routes**

```php
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\QuoteController;
use App\Http\Controllers\RabbitController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/rabbits', [RabbitController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/rabbit/edit/{id}', [RabbitController::class, 'edit']);
Route::put('/rabbit/update', [RabbitController::class, 'update']);
```

**`RabbitController.php`**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Rabbit;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RabbitController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return view('rabbits.index', ['rabbits' => Rabbit::all()]);
    }

    public function edit($id) {
        return view('rabbits.edit', ['rabbit' => Rabbit::where('breed_id', $id)->first()]);
    }

    public function update(Request $request) {
        echo("SOME SORT OF RESULT!");
        var_dump($request);
    }
}
```

Before I even hit the controller I get an exception reading:
`The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT.`

[image: URL request as defined by Laravel]

I really don't get what I'm doing wrong in this scenario

Comment: Browsers [can't send a PUT from a form](https://www.google.com/search?q=HTML+form+send+PUT), unfortunately.

Comment: To send a put request you will need to change the method to post and add `@method('PUT')` in your form. This will insert a hidden input for the method. Laravel will then automatically route this to the method specified by the put route.

Comment: `is it really that stupid`...don't ask me why, but that's how it is right now. In the beginning of HTML forms, GET and POST were all people really cared about I guess. The more nuanced approach of RESTful designs came a lot later, and for some reason browsers haven't caught up with it in that particular respect. You'd have to ask the makers of browsers / writers of standards why that is.

Comment: See https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/3577

Comment: @Aless55 - make an answer saying that and add the part where browsers are stupid and I'll accept it as the answer, 'cause that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated above in my comment:

To send a put request you will need to change the `method` to `POST` and add `@method('PUT')` in your form. This will insert a hidden input for the method. Laravel will then automatically route this request to the method specified by the put route in your routes file.

This is needed because as @ADyson writes, browsers are limited to `GET` and `POST` request.

And last but not least, browsers or in this case HTML forms are stupid.
Maybe someday this will be changed, who knows.